# Set Docker container env var at run time via AWS SSM Parameter Store

Tags: docker, circleci, aws-secrets-manager, aws-ssm, aws-parameter-store

I have a bit of a weird setup. I have a raw EC2 instance where I will run Docker containers. I want to set up some sort of CI/CD using CircleCI and [WatchTower](https://github.com/containrrr/watchtower)

Basically what will happen is WatchTower will poll the container registry and if there's a new image, will restart the other containers. CircleCI will handle any PR merges and then build and deploy the new container image.

This means that I'll need a way to pull *new* environment variables/secrets into the container and I want to do a one-time setup.

The plan is to pass in AWS credentials, either using `-e` or mounting `~/.aws/credentials` to the container on the first `docker run`.

When the container is deployed, it will use these credentials to set environment variables within the container, before starting the server. This means it will pull any new parameters on each restart.

How can I perform this last step? I'm also open to different ways of setting env vars in the container.

Comment: I know i'm three months to late, but you really really should look into Ec2 back Ecs. It literally does all of this for you.

Comment: @DevOverlord yeah, agreed it's probably the better option but the cost goes up a bit due to the extra infra needed, which is the constraint for the current setup.

Comment: You can use an ECS Capacity Provider to scale the EC2 Instances as needed. Our development environment at work is always at 0 and only scales up as needed and then scales back down when ECS doesn't need the instance anymore.